# Obtaining one a.s. convergence from another

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading a probability theory paper and it has a result that, in effect, says that if $X_k$ is a sequence of random variables, if $Y$ is a random variable, if $\phi_k$ is a random subsequence of $\{k\geq 1\}$ with $\{\phi_k-\phi_{k-1}\}_{k\geq 2}$ being i.i.d. random variables with finite expectation, if $A$ is some event, if $c$ is a constant, if
$$\frac{\log P(\{X_{\phi_k}\in A\}\vert Y)}{k}\xrightarrow{\rm{a.s.}}c$$
and if
$$\phi_k/k \xrightarrow{\rm{a.s.}} \mathbb{E}[\phi_2-\phi_1]$$ then
$$\frac{\log P(\{X_{k}\in A\}\vert Y)}{k}\xrightarrow{\rm{a.s.}}c/\mathbb{E}[\phi_2-\phi_1]$$

There is no explanation given in the paper and so, I assume its trivial but I don't understand why this would be true? I can attach the paper if specifics about $X_k,\phi_k,A$ are needed to answer the question. Thanks for your response.

EDIT: Here is the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.08564.pdf). It's in proposition 3.15 and the two equations I'm referring to are the last equation of page 18 and the first equation of page 19.

Comment: Yes it would be nice to attach the paper, since it may answer some questions: is there independence between $(X_i)$ and $(\phi_k)$? $P(X_k\in A)$ is deterministic as well as $P(X_{\phi_k}\in A)$ so why the almost sure convergence instead of a usual convergence?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Sure thing, I've attached the paper and edited the question. I'm not sure about the independence part but I meant $P(X_k\in A)$ to be a random variable. I'll edit that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is trivial because of the following:

Define $Z_{k}:=\log P(\{X_{k}\in A\}|Y)$

Then,
\begin{align}
\frac{Z_{\phi_k}}{k} &= \frac{Z_{\phi_k}}{\phi_k}\cdot \frac{\phi_k}{k} \\
\implies \frac{Z_{\phi_k}}{\phi_k} &\xrightarrow{\rm{a.s.}} \frac{c}{\mathbb{E}[\phi_2-\phi_1]}
\end{align}

This clearly means $\frac{Z_{k}}{k} \xrightarrow{\rm{a.s.}} \frac{c}{\mathbb{E}[\phi_2-\phi_1]}$.